# Cannot style my TabControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm getting used to styling slowly, especially in regards to Templates (DataTemplates, Templates, ControlTemplates etc).

However, I'm lost

I'm trying to have my TabItems all white (I'm not as far as Triggers yet so the selected item won't be shown), and the content to be grey. The entire thing is to be border-less.

I'm following the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms754137%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and my stripped down version is

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="20">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Border Background="Red">
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                          Margin="4"
                          ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                                    </Border>

                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                <Grid>

                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          ContentSource="Header"
                          Margin="12,2,12,2"
                          RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                                </Grid>

                            </ControlTemplate>

                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
        </TabControl>
```

My WPF only shows a thin red line across the screen.

I'm using the MVVM approach, so I can see that although I set the ItemsSource (to a property called Tabs), I'm not defining it else where.  The `Tabs` of which I'm binding too all have a property called Title. This Title should be seen in the `TabItem` header

So, I tried to update the following (in the TabItem styles)

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Title}" />
```

It makes no difference.

I can't see what I should be doing and can't see where I've gone wrong compared to the MSDN article.

My end goal is to have something like (where the non selected TabItems are white (I know I can use Triggers), the TabPanel is white, and the content is grey). The blurry bits are titles (text):

[image]

My question is, how can I show the Title property and remove the borders from the default TabControl's TabItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="20">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">

                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Border Background="White">
                                        <TabPanel Name="HeaderPanel"
                                            Grid.Row="0"
                                            Panel.ZIndex="1" 
                                            Margin="0" 
                                            IsItemsHost="True"
                                            KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Border Background="Teal" Grid.Row="1">
                                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectedContent"></ContentPresenter>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF3F3F3"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" >
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                <Grid>
                                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Title}" Margin="20,0,20,0"  />
                                </Grid>

                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>

                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />


                </Style>
                 </TabControl.Resources>
        </TabControl>
```

Also, make sure if you are using MVVM, you have the DataTemplate sorted for each View/ViewModel otherwise it (the content) won't have a height and appear as if it's not there!

Answer (score 0):

You should only provide a value for the `TabItem.Template` property if you want to redefine what a `TabItem` should look like... I'm guessing that you just want a normal `TabItem`. Instead of trying to define a new `ControlTemplate` to bind your `Title` property, just set that as the `TabItem.Header` value instead:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}" />
    ...
</Style>
```

Comment: I started this way, but, when I did `<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />` the border remained so I thought I had to overwrite it. Whilst your suggestion certainly works (it shows the Title), can I still remove the border?

Comment: You *can* use the `Template` property if you *do* want to redefine what the `TabItem` looks like... I just incorrectly assumed that you had done that by accident.